# Comparing SIM card IMSI upon boot up

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The service class

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class StartActivityAtBoot extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, CompareIMSI.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

The compare SIM card IMSI class

```
public class CompareIMSI extends Service{

Context context;
TelephonyManager operator;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    compareSIM();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void compareSIM(){

    final String STORAGE = "Storage";
    SharedPreferences unique = getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, 0);
    final String storedIMSI = unique.getString("simIMSI", "");
    final String currentIMSI = getSubscriberId().toString();

    if (!storedIMSI.equals(currentIMSI)){
        Intent i = new Intent(CompareIMSI.this, ScreenLockActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

public String getSubscriberId(){

    String IMSI = null;
    String serviceName = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
    TelephonyManager m_telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(serviceName);
    int deviceType = m_telephonyManager.getPhoneType();
    switch (deviceType) {
        case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM):
            break;
        case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA):
            break;
        case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE):
            break;
        default:
            break;
     }
     IMSI = m_telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
     return IMSI;
}
}
```

I wish the apps able to compare the stored SIM card IMSI with the current inserted IMSI upon boot up, if the IMSIs are different, then the apps will bring user to another activity after bootup... What is wrong with my coding?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't comparing the IMSI, you are comparing the IMEI (which is the phone's ID and it won't ever change).

To get the IMSI you need:

```
IMSI = m_telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, `getSubscriberId()` is the correct method, and by the way, when you receive the boot_completed broadcast, the "imsi" is usually not available.